# The Suspended Account

Tags: discussion

I read over the [Temporarily Suspended](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) post to ensure I understand what can cause such punishment as I wasn't sure why his rep would be stripped while suspended; but now it makes better sense.

When it comes to [plagiarism](http://www.plagiarism.org/plagiarism-101/what-is-plagiarism/) a person would think that someone who has been around the community so long would know to put an "easy" and "simple" reference to the material they get the detail from when posting. Having an account suspended being around for so long and having so much rep must be a humiliating experience.

### Questions

- Does the [SU](http://superuser.com) community have the ability to review the stats from any particular account regarding [suspension](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) and previous occurrences?

  - I wasn't sure if there was anything at https://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/queries for example where you can change the ID number or name of the account being searched to find such statistics?

While I may not be the most active account on SU , I at times also try to hop over to [Review](https://superuser.com/review) to go thru what I can as well as answering a question here or there.  I've never seen the HarryMC profile image there nor many of the other BIG rep dogs like they're not putting in any time at this level. Since I've wondered this in the past and only now that I've noticed this with the BIGGEST dog of them all's account being in this state, it's a good time for me to ask Meta.

- So I wasn't sure as per [Temporarily Suspended](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) where it specifically states "***The user never gives anything back to the community, but only takes.***" if such a classification would be applicable where an account doesn't do any review duties?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We don't go into specifics outside the [generic suspension message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23385/avoid-the-streisand-effect-be-clear-about-the-reason-when-suspending-an-accoun) for specific suspensions.

I can talk about the *general* questions you have.

Generally though, if you're the one suspended, you'd get some idea of what it is, and we don't hand them out lightly. Suspensions are *specific* and reviewing isn't mandatory. Very Importantly

> At the end of this timed suspension period, your reputation will be recalculated, and your account will resume as normal. We don't hold grudges. The point of all this is to address the behavior. If the behavior improves, you are welcome back.

As for the specific questions you have

- Does the SU community have the ability to review the stats from any particular account regarding suspension and previous occurrences?

Its mod only. Suspensions arn't meant to be a long term black mark. Ideally people learn from their suspensions, and we'd never have to review their past records. That's why suspensions are always paired with mod messages.

- if such a classification would be applicable where an account doesn't do any review duties?

Nope. There's utterly no obligation to review. Review bans don't really affect the rest of your abilities on the site either. You'll *never* be suspended for  not reviewing.

Comment: Thanks for the clear and concise answer!!